# Suspending makes loud beep (Linux Mint 19.3)

Tags: linux, linux-mint, thinkpad

Every time when I suspend my computer there is a short high pitch loud beep, it happens when I suspend it and when I wake it back up but not not when I turn the computer on or shut it down.
This beep is super annoying can someone please help.
(I'm using a Lenovo Thinkpad sl500)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this beep comes from the BIOS (or UEFI firmware) and happens on a variety of ThinkPad models.  You can look into the BIOS/UEFI settings and see if it can be configured on your model.

Comment: Thank you so much, it stops beeping now